# RadioGroup add RadioButton duplicate when standby phone android

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a problem with `RadioGroup` and add dynamically `RadioButton`
I have this function:

```
private void createRadio() {
        RadioGroup rgp= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams rprms;

        for(int i=0;i<radios.length();i++){
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
            try {
                JSONObject object = radios.getJSONObject(i);
                radioButton.setText(object.getString("name"));
                radioButton.setId(object.getInt("id"));
                rprms= new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                assert rgp != null;
                rgp.addView(radioButton, rprms);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Where `radios` is a JSONArray that I retrieve from my db.
And my problem is that when I put in "stand by" my app, and so the activity is stopped when i reopen my activity I found the value of radiogroup duplicate.
Example:
if in my App have 3 radio button like:

 1 

 2 

3

When I stanby phone without close app, and reopen app after unlocked phone, i find this:

 1 

 2 

3

 1 

 2 

3

I Believe that the problem is the `rgp.addView` that add `radioButton` without check if radiobutton already exists.
There is a method for check if radioGroup is already populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do any of following:-

1) Remove all RadioButtons from RadioGroup before adding new ones as

```
    radioGroup.removeAllViews();
```

2) Check if RadioGroup is already populated

```
    boolean alreadyPopulated = radioGroup.getChildCount() > 0;
```